# Simple Display Results from Database

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have set up correctly the parameters for Zend_Db::factory and then I am querying like:

```
$select = $db->select()
->from('imdb')
->limit(10);

$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Question:
Why I do not see anything displayed?

I continue and I am trying to display results by creating a new object

```
$moviesTBL = new Application_Model_DbTable_Imdb();
$this->view->albums = $moviesTBL->fetchAll();
```

If I combine it with a view it works fine BUT fetches all rows!!! How to make it fetch only first 10?

```
foreach($this->albums as $key=> $value)
{
echo $value ->rank.' '.$value->rating.' '.$value->title.' '.$value->year.' '.$value->number_of_votes.'<br>';
}
```

pana4219

```
Posts: 2
Joined: Mon Nov 04, 2013 6:45 pm
```

Answer (score 3):

Try somthing like this:

```
$select = $db->select()
->from('imdb')
->limit(10);

$result = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Other example:

```
$class = new Zend_Db_Table();
$db = $class->getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select();
$select->from('imdb');
$select->limit(10);

$result = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root"
resources.db.params.dbname = ""
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initDb() { 
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter());
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying but I did not manage to make it work. If I use $select = $db->select()
->from('imdb')
->limit(10); as you suggested, how can I display the results??? $result = $db->fetchAll($select) by itself does not work. I guess with a view-> bla bla and a foreach in the view itself. Can you help me on that? On the other hand if I write $moviesTBL = new Application_Model_DbTable_Imdb();
$this->view->albums = $moviesTBL->fetchAll(); and inside the fetchAll I use the $result parameter so that it only fetches the first 10, it does not seem to work either.