# Object of class Application_Model_Rawdata could not be converted to string

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework, converters

I have a big problem.
When I called my Website with Zend Framework, I get this error:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Application_Model_Rawdata could not be converted to string in C:\xampp*****\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml on line 13

View Script line 13:

```
<p class="announcement-heading"><?php $this->rawdata; ?></p>
```

IndexController

```
$readraw = new Application_Model_Rawdata();
$readraw->readRawData();        
$this->view->rawdata = $readraw;
```

The Class

```
class Application_Model_Rawdata extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function readRawData() {
        $dbTableRawdata = new Application_Model_DbTable_Rawdata();
        $rowset = $dbTableRawdata->fetchAll();
        $rowcount = count($rowset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Application_Model_Rawdata extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function readRawData() {
        $dbTableRawdata = new Application_Model_DbTable_Rawdata();
        $rowset = $dbTableRawdata->fetchAll();
        $rowcount = count($rowset);
        return $rowcount;
    }
}
```

I don't recommend using `count()` to get total number of records.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Application_Model_Rawdata could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\***\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml on line 13

Comment: Hello! See my example here, you are doing in wrong way to get database records.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801818/simple-display-results-from-database/19802485#19802485[/link]

sorry I speak English not well.